# How to get all English words in an array for autocomplete?

Tags: android, api, kotlin, tags

I am working on an Android app where we add post with some tags like in Stack Overflow. I observed that people in my app add tags with different patterns like they use technology as tech, techno, technologies or startup, start up or start-up so when they do something like this then sorting post on searching is a challenge. I mean when they search for startup they cannot see post tagged with start up or start-up.

So I thought to change the `edittext` where users write tags to an `autoCompleteTextView` so now they must have to add tags from the list provided in the app. But for the list of words I need a list/array of strings but I can't include them in my app as there are millions of words and they will increase the size of the app up to 5 to 6mb. So I want a free `API` for my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many APIs are for this one of them is [here](https://github.com/dwyl/english-words).

> A text file containing 479k English words for all your
> dictionary/word-based projects e.g: auto-completion / autosuggestion

You can get tutorials on this. If you want to use it in android with kotlin by just searching it like "Kotlin with Retrofit 2".